# DIY voltmeter safety concerns

Tags: ac, opto-isolator, rectifier, atmega328p, voltmeter

I would like to build a voltmeter using an ATMEGA328P that measures AC mains voltage. I came across the following schematic which appears to be what I am looking for:

[image: Voltmeter Schematic]

The top part of the circuit goes to an analog port while the bottom goes to ground.

Since I don't usually work with mains voltage, I prefer to err on the side of caution and have two basic questions.

1. Since the purpose of the 220 kΩ resistors appears to be rectifying the voltage, can other values be used, such as 10 kΩ or even 1 MΩ?
2. To provide adequate isolation, can a PC817 opto-coupler be used, and if so, where in the circuit should it be placed?

Any other comments or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Are you open to the suggestion of using a standard, off-the-shelf AC wall transformer to step down the mains voltage first? There are widely available 120V/240V AC transformers that can step down to 6.3VAC or similar low voltage levels. This provides the galvanic isolation and keeps the high voltage grid dragons neatly confined behind a commercial, off-the-shelf component, that likely already has the various UL/CE safety ratings. Trying to sense mains voltage without a transformer is a much more serious undertaking.

Comment: Do you need to know the amplitude of the AC voltage, or do you just need to know that it is present?

Comment: resistors do not rectify voltage

Comment: How are you powering the Arduino? It can't safely be connected to a computer USB port. Commercial handheld multimeters use batteries so their ground is isolated from the circuit under test.

Comment: Some quick replies: I would like to know the amplitude of the AC voltage. The ATMEGA would be powered separately at 5VDC using a buck transformer. If I step down the voltage first before measuring it, does this mean that if the source voltage is 25% less than what it should be (let's say 165V instead of 220V) and I step it down to 8VAC, would I be also measuring 25% less (i.e., 6VAC instead of 8VAC)? Finally,,apologies about resistors rectifying voltage, my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since the purpose of the 220 kΩ resistors appears to be rectifying the voltage, can other values be used, such as 10 kΩ or even 1 MΩ?

No. The purpose of the resistors is to make a resistor ladder. 1001 kilo-ohm through the whole ladder, 1 kilo-ohm through the measured part. This makes it a 1000:1 resistor ladder.  Giving 0.12V nominal across the 1000 ohm resistor at 120V.

However, it is also to place high resistance between the nutty experimenter and the ***lethal*** 120 volt or 230 volt utility current.  Plug 440K ohm and 230V into Ohm's Law and you see worst-case current is limited to less than a milliamp.

> The top part of the circuit goes to an analog port while the bottom goes to ground.

The bottom goes to ground?? You do realize both sides of this thing will be at 50V or 70V above actual safety ground.  Or in most of the world, 100 to 130 volts above actual earth.

By your choice of circuit, I assumed you were OK with that because the Arduino is battery powered or something.

> buck transformer

*A $1.00 transformer???* I think you are talking about a switching power supply that may not provide isolation, and are simply being imprecise with your words.   Playing with AC power is no place to get sloppy. You should say exactly whqt things are.

Any "transformer" that has the word "buck" associated with it is probably a bad idea.

> Any other comments or suggestions are welcome.

You are playing with lightning, Ben Franklin.

You would be better off using a literal transformer, which will do accurate and proportional voltage reduction provided it is loaded lightly.  A 6-volt AC actual transformer at the front of this thing will reduce your voltage proportionately and allow you to both power the Arduino and measure the voltage without misadventure.   The actual transformer will orovide actual isolation.